# Why Is the Solution of a Linear Nonhomogeneous Constant-Coefficient Differential Equation the Sum of a Particular and Homogeneous Solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Why Is the Solution of a Linear Nonhomogeneous Constant-Coefficient Differential Equation the Sum of a Particular and Homogeneous Solution?

My textbook gives the following proof:

Let $x_c(t)$ be a solution of the homogeneous equation and $x_p(t)$ be a solution of the particular equation.

$a\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b\dfrac{dx}{dt} + cx = a\left(
\dfrac{d^2x_c}{dt^2} + \dfrac{d^2x_p}{dt^2} \right) + b\left(
\dfrac{dx_c}{dt} + \dfrac{dx_p}{dt} \right) + c(x_c + x_p)$

$= \left( a\dfrac{d^2x_c}{dt^2} + b\dfrac{dx_c}{dt} + cx_c \right) +
\left( a\dfrac{d^2x_p}{dt^2} + b\dfrac{dx_p}{dt} + cx_p \right)$

$= 0 + f(t) = f(t) $

I don't see how this proves that a homogeneous solution and a particular solution are required to find the solution of a linear non homogeneous constant-coefficient differential equation?

In fact, the proof shows that we end up with $= 0 + f(t) = f(t) $ where $f(t)$ is what we were seeking all along. Therefore, since $\left( a\dfrac{d^2x_c}{dt^2} + b\dfrac{dx_c}{dt} + cx_c \right) = 0$, what was the point of the solution to the homogeneous equation? It seems that the homogeneous solution was redundant from the beginning, since only the particular solution, $\left( a\dfrac{d^2x_p}{dt^2} + b\dfrac{dx_p}{dt} + cx_p \right)$, contributed towards the solution of the linear non homogeneous constant-coefficient differential equation ($\left( a\dfrac{d^2x_p}{dt^2} + b\dfrac{dx_p}{dt} + cx_p \right) = f(t)$).

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify concept.

**EDIT**

I've received 3 answers; none of which address my question or do it sufficiently. My question is very clear: How does the above calculation show that both a particular solution and a homogeneous solution are required for a general solution? I then mentioned that the homogeneous solutions ends up equating to $0$ and the particular solution equates to $f(x)$; in other words,  it seems that the particular solution was the only thing required to get the general solution $f(x)$, which seemingly makes the homogeneous solution redundant? What am I misunderstanding?

Given the poor response it has received, I am going to request that a moderator delete this question.

Comment: Now that it's 3 years later, I hope you've learned some more math and that now you feel stupid for berating three people who exactly and correctly answered your question.

Comment: @B.Goddard Haha, I'm surprised you remembered this! I'm going to read over this again, and probably cringe with embarrassed whilst doing so. I might have to delete some comments to wipe history of my past childishness/ungratefulness.

Comment: Well, I didn't remember.  Someone actually upvoted my answer this morning, so I went back and looked.   I leave all my embarrassing stuff up.  It's good for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is to find *some* solution of the ODE, well, then finding one particular solution $x_p(t)$ is enough. But that solution might not be the right one, if you have additional conditions (boundary values, etc.). Usually one needs to know *all* the solutions of the ODE, in order to pick the one that satisfies the extra conditions.

The computation that you have reproduced from your textbook shows that $x_p(t)+x_c(t)$ is *another* solution of the same ODE (if $x_c(t)\neq 0$), so this indicates a way of finding more solutions than just $x_p(t)$. (The point here is that, as you have realized, only $x_p(t)$ gives a contribution $f(t)$ to the right-hand side, and adding $x_c(t)$ doesn't spoil that.)

But that still doesn't really explain the main issue, which is that you find *all* the solutions in this way. This is where the subtraction argument comes in. Suppose you have happened to find one particular solution $x_{p,1}(t)$ while your friend found another one $x_{p,2}(t)$. Then the difference $x_c(t)=x_{p,2}(t)-x_{p,1}(t)$ will satisfy the homogeneous equation, since you get $\ldots=f(t)-f(t)=0$ in the right-hand side when plugging in. So two different particular solutions to your ODE can't be arbitrarily different; they can only differ by a solution to the homogeneous ODE. That's why you know *all* the solutions to your ODE if you know (a) one of them to begin with, and (b) all the solutions $x_c(t)$ of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: Well, the very clear answer is that the calculation in your textbook does **not** show why you need both! That's what my last paragraph tries to explain.

Comment: By the way, if you think that the general solution is $f(x)$, then it's not strange that that you're not getting any of the explanations. It's $x(t)$ that's the solution. The function $f(t)$ is just the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: That's what I tried to explain in my second paragraph: “The computation that you have reproduced from your textbook shows that...”

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how it can be made clearer... If you know one solution to the original ODE, and a nonzero solution to the corresponding homogeneous ODE, then you can add them to get **another** solution to the original ODE. That's exactly what the computation shows, no more, no less.

Comment: Yes, if you do it with $x_p(t)$ only, you get $f(t)$ in the right-hand side. That's what it means for $x_p(t)$ to be a solution. And if you do it with $x_p(t)+x_c(t)$, you *also* get $f(t)$, just *because* $x_c(t)$ doesn't contribute. And that means that $x_p(t)+x_c(t)$ is *also* a solution. Which is the point: you get **another** solution to the same equation. If $x_c(t)$ had given a nonzero contribution, you wouldn't get $f(t)$, hence $x_p(t)+x_c(t)$ wouldn't have been a solution.

Comment: No, no, no, it is definitely **not** true that $x_c(t)+x_p(t)$ is the same thing as $f(t)$! Maybe that's the whole source of your confusion?

Comment: When you take $x_p(t)$ **and do certain operations on it**, then you get $f(t)$. And **the same operations** on the function $x_p(t)+x_c(t)$ **also** gives $f(t)$.

Comment: And the **most general function** that will give $f(t)$ **when you do those operations** is obtained as $x_p(t)+x_c(t)$ where $x_c(t)$ is the most general function which gives **zero** when you do those operations on it.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: Great! You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is some linear function (doesn't have to be about differential equations), $f(x)=z$ and $f(y)=z$ then $f(x)-f(y)=0=f(x-y)$. Thus $x-y$ solves the homogeneous equation. Therefore it is *enough* to find a particular solution and the general homogeneous solution, because the difference of two particular solutions will always be one of the homogeneous solutions. You don't *have* to proceed this way but it is usually easier. Just taking a particular solution will not give you all solutions unless there are no nontrivial homogeneous solutions (which never happens in ordinary differential equations).

Comment: @ThePointer It's another presentation of the same idea.

Comment: @ThePointer My last sentence addresses that issue, I think: the homogeneous solution is indeed "destroyed" when you substitute it into the equation, but it wasn't zero to begin with, so it gives you a new solution. For example, there are more solutions to $y'=1$ than just $y=x$, there is $x+C$, and that $C$ is coming from the homogeneous solution, i.e. the solutions to $y'=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The theory of linear, 2nd-order equations says that the general solution is a double infinity of solutions.  When you solve the homogeneous equation, there are 2 arbitrary constants.  Letting those constants vary over all the real numbers gives the double infinity of solutions.

The particular solution to the nonhomogenous equation is just one solution.  You you need infinity-squared minus one more solutions to have the general solution.  By happy coincidence*, if you add a homogeneous solution to the particular solution, you get another particular solution.  Since there is a double infinity of homogeneous solutions, we can form a double infinity of non-homogeneous solutions.  In fact, ALL solutions can be constructed this way, so it is, in fact, the general solution.

Why do we need the general solution?  Because the particular solution has no arbitrary constants in it, which means you can't solve a corresponding IVP.  With the arbitrary constants, you can solve ANY corresponding IVP.

*Yeah, I know.

Comment: @ThePointer  I'm pretty sure it exactly answers the question.  Are you sure you asked what you wanted?

Comment: Well, I never mentioned infinities. I'm just a student trying to understand the concept I posted in the OP. I even provided the proof and specified the reasoning that I do not understand. I'm probably just too stupid to understand your answer, but none of it looks like it addresses my post.

Comment: The infinities are the point.  You add ONE nonhom solution to each of the infinitely many hom solutions and it gives you infinitely many nonhom sols.  That's why we add homs to nonhoms.  And the reason it's necessary, is that it give you ALL nonhom solutions.