# Sum of Homogeneous and Particular Solution Is the Full Solution Set?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was hoping if someone could point me to a (hopefully) not too technical proof of why the sum of the homogeneous and particular solution to a (linear) differential equation yields the full solution set that to that differential equation.

Intuitively, I understand this as follows (from the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174982/why-is-the-solution-of-a-linear-nonhomogeneous-constant-coefficient-differential) question):

"Suppose I find one particular solution $x_{(p,1)}(t)$ while my friend finds another one $x_{(p,2)}(t)$. Then the difference $x_c(t)=x_{(p,2)}(t)−x_{(p,1)}(t)$ will satisfy the homogeneous equation, since you get $…=f(t)−f(t)=0…$ in the right-hand side when substituting. So two different particular solutions to my ODE can't be arbitrarily different; they can only differ by a solution to the homogeneous ODE."

I am trying to find a way this can be formalized. I am not looking for a proof on how the sum of the homogeneous and particular solutions satisfy the original differential equation - I am trying to see why this is the full solution set.

Thanks!

Comment: But this quote already is such a proof.